# Whats the correct way, using "init" or "didmove"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, swift3

Language: Swift 3.0 --- IDE : Xcode 8.0 beta 2 --- Project : iOS Game (SpriteKit)

I create a game for iOS and i know Apple is really strict with their rules to accept the app/game. So i want to know which is the correct way to setup a game.

I learned from google to create a new SpriteKit Project and do the following setup :

In **GameViewController.swift** clear viewDidLoad() and add all this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let skView = self.view as! SKView

    let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

In **GameScene.swift** delete everything and leave this code :

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        // add all the code of the game here...
    }

}
```

**and develop my game inside override init**

But I think thats actually wrong to start the game with init. And that the right way is to use the didMove() method. So should the code be written inside here? :

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    <#code#>
}
```

Does anyone know which one is the correct way? And why? Also if its wrong the way i do it, can you explain me how to use didMove method?

Don't know if this is a silly question just bothered me that using init is wrong and wanted to ask if someone knows more about this.

Comment: I would not recommend this -> `let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)`,  Use `GameScene(fileNamed:)` or `GameScene()` with `scaleMode = .ResizeFill`.  `GameScene(size:)` should be used with the other 3 scaleModes, `.Fill`, `.AspectFill`, and `.AspectFit` only when you want the scene to have a static size across all devices.  Does it hurt using the way you are using, Only when you have the view size dynamically change, but hey if you can program yourself to stop mistakes before they are created,  then that is progress.

Comment: There is no correct or wrong way, but that way you presented is how I create my games since I use .AspectFill and make the size the resolution of an iPad. Also, init is to initialize class variables/initializes the values that the class has (prevent values from being nil). didMoveToView is called when the view has been presented to the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Overriding the SKScene init

You can override the initializers of `SKScene` like described by @Knight0fDragon

```
class GameScene : SKScene {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()             
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setup()
    }

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        setup()
    }

    func setup()
    {
        // PUT YOUR CODE HERE

    }
}
```

### Or you can use the didMove(to:)

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)
        // PUT YOUR CODE HERE <-----
    }
}
```

The `init` is called only when the scene is initialised.
The `didMove` is called when the scene is presented into the view.

Comment: So I just copy-paste the same code I have on init inside didMove? And does didMove run 1 time and setup the game and end, just like init?

Comment: @pRivaT3BuG: `didMove` happens when the scene is presented into the `SKView`. It is executed only once (unless you remove it from the view and add it again but it's pretty uncommon). However it is the right place to customize your scene. It's like when into a `UIKit` app you set up your ViewController inside  `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with overriding the SKScene init, in fact, you want to use this to set up the initial state of the scene.  The children are present after you call init with coder as well. This allows you to initialize and prepare a scene long before a transition is even needed. (Less time on a loading screen, YAY). Using the `didMove(to:view)` is actually not a great place, because if you design a game that utilizes multiple scenes, then this will be fired every time a transition occurs, forcing you to add an if block  to do a check.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: If you override the init(s) like in the example you won't be able to call `GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")` from `GameViewController`. Apple docs is clear: `didMove` is the right place to set up the scene.

Comment: @appzYourLife,  yes you can,  in order to get access to convenience methods, you need to override all designated inits

Comment: @appzYourLife,  unfortunately, when it comes to Sprite Kit,  the documentation is terrible,  and Apple recommends things that are really not necessary.  I have already mentioned 2 reasons as to why it is not always good to use the didMove to setup your scene,

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: `yes you can, in order to get access to convenience methods, you need to override all designated inits` ok but I said `If you override the init(s) like in the example you won't be able to call GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")`. By the way can you provide a GameScene with a working overridden version of `init?(fileNamed: String)`? I would like to perform some tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118226/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-appzyourlife).

Comment: @appzYourLife the required.init does not run my code. I tried to change backgroundColor but it wont change. But if I add my code to the 2 other inits it changes the color. So which one should I use?

Comment: @pRivaT3BuG: It's a long story. **--Solution 1--)** Just use `didMove` **--Solution 2--**: read the chat I had with @Knight0fDragon

Comment: @appzYourLife I read it... too hard for me I think :P I will read it again more carefully. Thanks for your time both :)

Comment: @pRivaT3BuG,  That is because you are using `GameScene(size:)` Place your code there ( I have already commented you should not be using that anyway)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thats what I wrote in my GameViewController : let skView = self.view as! SKView---
      
        let scene = GameScene()---
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill---
        
        skView.presentScene(scene)

Comment: if you are using init()  then you place the code in the init() method you are overriding

Comment: or, make your life easy,  create a new method for setup,  and have all 3 init call the setup method

Comment: @Knight0fDragon OK. I liked the last comment. Thats what Im gonna do. Thanks :)

Comment: "didMove(to:)" what a terrible naming choice for a function whose standard usage is to setup the scene