# Should I set up a SKScene programmatically in the init method or in didMove(toView:)?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Should I set up a SKScene programmatically (i.e. create subnodes, add child nodes to the current scene, layout, etc.) in the init method or in didMove(toView:) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the correct way, using "init" or "didmove"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567125/whats-the-correct-way-using-init-or-didmove)

Comment: inits are meant for initializing. But in scene's init, self.view is nil. If you need a view for any calculations, you should use didMove(toView:)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the initialization of your nodes should go in the "init". This is where the initial setup of the view occurs, this involves creating `SKNodes` and setting this nodes to their positions. If you have any other properties you want to apply to your nodes, then you can do this one time setup in the sceneDidMove to view.

example

```
    class GameScene : SKScene {
       var player : SKSpriteNode?

           override init(size: CGSize) {
            let playerSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 60)
            self.player = SKSpriteNode((texture: nil, color: .cyan, size: playerSize) 
            self.addChild(player)
            player.position.x  = size.width / 2
            player.position.y = size.height / 2
            player.zPosition = 99

            super.init(size: size)
            // you can only call functions after super.init

        }

    override func sceneDidLoad() {
    //setup Code

        }

    }
}
```